# AppleScript error -10000 when writing to dropbox directory

Tags: applescript

I have pasted together an apple script to save email attachments to a directory. Everything works fine, but when I set the output to a dropbox directory, I get an error message:

```
Result:
error "Mail got an error: To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info." number -10000
```

The line producing the error is the one starting with `save anAttachment to...` in the following script:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theMessages to messages of mailbox "Inbox" of account "xxx@yyy.zzz"
    repeat with theMessage in theMessages
        set theOutputFolder to ("/.../Dropbox (Company)/") as string
        repeat with anAttachment in (get mail attachments in theMessage)
            set theAttachmentName to name of anAttachment
            set theSavePath to theOutputFolder & theAttachmentName
            save anAttachment in theSavePath
        end repeat      
    end repeat
end tell
```

In a non-dropbox directory everything works.

The flags of the dropbox directory are set as follows:

```
~ $ ls -FLAG -lhd@ Dropbox\ \(Company)                                
drwx------@ 15 username  staff   480B Apr  8 13:52 Dropbox (Company)/
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32B
```

I tried to run `chmod go+rw` on the directory, but that did not help.

GetInfo on the directory yields:

[image]

Changing everyone to Read&Write does not help either.

Comment: _"/.../Dropbox (Company)/"_ is not a valid filepath.  It also doesn't need to be coerced into a `string`, since it is already a `string` to begin with.  But, with regards to the specific problem, if you read the error message, that gives a big clue as to the likely cause: it sounds like either Mail.app or your script don't have write persmission that's needed to write to that folder.  Follow its instructions by going to Finder, finding the folder, choosing `File > Get Info` from the menu, and adding or changing the necessary permissions.

Comment: @CJK - thanks a lot for your comment! I abbreviated the file path in the script, it is actually "/Users/...", so in the full version it is a valid file path. Regarding the second part, I am not sure what to do. I can save an attachment in that folder from the Mail app directly, so in principle it should have permissions to write to that directory. And in my understanding the "Sharing & Permissions:" part of Get Info is about who has access to Mail, not what permissions the app itself has. Still confused...

Comment: How are you running the script—from within _Script Editor_ or another way ? Whatever is executing the script, e.g. _Script Editor_, does that thing have permission to write to the Dropbox folder ?  One thing you could do is open Terminal and run this command: `ls -FLAG -lhd@  "/Users/.../Dropbox (Company)/"`.  If you add the output from that as an edit to your question at the end, that'll give us insight.  Also taking a screenshot of the Info window for the folder to include the ACL permissions at the bottom.

Comment: I doubt that Mail works with POSIX paths. Use an HFS path `set theOutputFolder to (path to home folder as text) & “Dropbox (Company):”`

Comment: @vadian - no that was not it. When I use a POSIX path for another local directory, it works...

Comment: When you say "it did not help", does this mean that the permissions were successfully changed but the script still could not access it; or that the permissions could not be changed ?  Because looking at those permissions, they seem a little restrictive.  You might also need to give Mail disk access in _`System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Files & Folders / Full Disk Access`_

Comment: As a last resort, since you mentioned you're able to save the attachments to other folders, you could create a folder into which you can download the attachments using your script, and then use _System Events_ to move the folder into your Dropbox.

Comment: @CJK - thanks a lot - I meant that changing the permissions did not let the script access the directory. Giving `Full disk access` (and `File & Folders`) to both Mail and Script Editor did help either, i.e. script could not access. I guess I will have to go with your last suggestion to use `System Events` once I have save the documents to one location.

Comment: So I have found out something else. The script cannot even write to my home directory (`/Users/divingtobi/`), but only to my `/Users/divingtobi/Downloads` directory. This brings me a step further, now I need to identify the difference between these two directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you get to the bottom of what is preventing you from writing out to folders other than your Downloads folder (which presumably includes subfolders in the Downloads folder), here's a barebones script that should save mail attachments to the folder *`~/Downloads/Mail Attachments/`*.

I've put a filter on the messages being acted upon as retrieving ***every*** message in a mailbox is potentially very costly.  This retrieves messages from the previous three days:

```
tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents" to tell (make new folder ¬
        with properties {name:"~/Downloads/Mail Attachments"}) to set ¬
        directory to the POSIX path


tell application id "com.apple.Mail"
        set _M to a reference to (every message in the inbox whose ¬
                date received > ((my date named 0.0) - 3 * days))

        repeat with A in _M's mail attachments
                set f to the directory & "/" & A's name
                save A in (f as POSIX file)
        end repeat
end tell
```

You could perhaps add code to migrate the "Mail Attachments" folder from your Downloads folder to your Dropbox folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write the attachments to any directory I wanted by changing the part where I write to opening a file handle, and using using that to write the attachment into the directory. Instead of `save anAttachment in theSavePath` I use

```
set fp to open for access theSavePath with write permission
write (anAttachment) to fp
close access fp
```

That does the trick, though it does not explain why the original method did not work...

Comment: This still does not work. There are only 360bytes written to the file... investigating further. The files all start with `dle2 obj X formenum D`.

Comment: No, it doesn't... It's very strange.  You could try resetting permissions by [resetting the NVRAM/PRAM/SMC](https://www.macworld.com/article/224955/how-to-reset-a-macs-nvram-pram-and-smc.html).

Comment: Regarding the file contents, it's because you've told it to write the AppleScript `attachment` object to file rather than the contents of the attachment.  That you're able to write to any directory using **`write`** might suggest this is a sandboxing issue.

Comment: Changing this to `write content of anAttachment to fp` also results in a 428 bytes long file, so no progress here. Investigating further...

Comment: See my previous comment. 420 bytes long is correct given your command.

Comment: So I still have not figured out what the reason for the permissions is, and I have in the meantime solved the problem by picking up the mail from my main script, which is in python. Worked with a couple of lines of code there, no trouble.